# Any tool other than Valgrind to monitor memory usage for running processes in Linux?

Tags: linux, memory-management

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/301576/how-do-i-tell-valgrind-to-memcheck-forked-processes/301587#301587) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/301576/how-do-i-tell-valgrind-to-memcheck-forked-processes/) says that there's no way to attach Valgrind to an already running process.
Are there any other tools for Linux that can report on memory usage but can attach to a process that's already running?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use tools like `pmap` or [ps_mem.py](http://www.pixelbeat.org/scripts/ps_mem.py) to get more details about the memory use of running processes than you get from `top`. You won't get all the fancy features from Valgrind like detecting memory leaks and such.

Answer (score 1):

All app data should be in

```
/proc/<PID>/
```